# Cooking beef for pepper steak

Tags: beef, restaurant-mimicry, stir-fry

From American-"Chinese" restaurants, I usually order a dish called "Pepper Steak with Onions". This seems to be a simple enough dish, mostly a straightforward stir-fry, except for one unique characteristic: the beef comes out soft and easy to chew, much like chicken.

How is this achieved? Is it a certain cut of meat? A certain cooking technique?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Chinese restaurants tenderize their meat?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20506/how-do-chinese-restaurants-tenderize-their-meat)

Comment: Disagree that this is a duplicate: OP is asking about which cut to use in addition to any tenderization technique (which may come before or during cooking).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meat in stir-fries is often velveted. That makes for a supremely soft chunk of meat, and it can be done with any type of meat. This answer actually addresses chicken: [How to cook extremely soft chicken?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40922/how-to-cook-extremely-soft-chicken/40924#40924), but it applies just as well to beef. It's usually done with egg and cornstarch, but sometimes it's done with a small amount baking soda instead, as in this recipe for [Beef and Broccoli](http://dragonchef.hubpages.com/hub/The-secret-behind-chinese-beef-and-broccoli).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Jolenealaska's answer the beef is cut across the grain, and very thin. It also helps to start with a tender cut like sirloin or rib.